# Number of "left-to-right" walks on a line graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G_n$ be the line graph on $n$ nodes.  An example when $n=4$:

[image]

Let $a_n(k)$ be the number of walks on this graph of length $k$, which start at node $1$ and end at node $n$. $a_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence.  It's easier to write it if instead we consider $b_n(\ell)$, which is the number of walks on $G$ having $\ell$ "lefts" (that is, going from a node $j$ to a node $j-1$).  Note that $b_n(\ell) = a_n(2\ell+n-1)$:

$$b_n(\ell) = \begin{cases}
               0 & \ell < 0\\
               1 & \ell = 0\\
              \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1}\binom{n-i}{i}b_n(\ell-i) & \ell>0
               \end{cases}$$
[Note: I could change the upper bound on that sum to $\frac{n}{2}$, but I think this way is more symmetric.]

Is there a combinatorial proof of this?

*Side note*: These sequences are pretty interesting.  $b_3(\ell)=2^\ell$, and $b_4(\ell) = F_{2\ell+1}$ (the Fibonacci numbers).

Comment: Note that you can rewrite this as

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n-i}ib_n(\ell-i)=0\;.
$$

Comment: Found a paper that proves this identity: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X7790019X